# Listview with multiple columns not acting properly when height of Item expanded

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hello I need a multicolumn control with variable heights and with expand/collapse capability. My approach so far is this-

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <control:UCNewsFeed Margin="6" DataContext="{Binding Post}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

please notice that UCNewsFeed is a usercontrol which is given below-

```
   <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="57"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>              
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid x:Name="namePanel">
                 <StackPanel x:Name="nameContainer">
                      <TextBlock>Lamia Mehreen</TextBlock>
                      <TextBlock>Monday at 12:02pm</TextBlock>
                      <Button/>
                 </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            <Border x:Name="hiddenPanel" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="1">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="editPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <RichTextBox/>
                            <Button Margin="0" Foreground="{x:Null}" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" BorderThickness="0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" Width="37" Height="37"/>
                    </StackPanel>
             </Border>
        </Grid>
```

[image]
The layout is so far okay. The problem arises when "hiddenPanel"'s visibility is switched to visible from code behind. The entire row of the listview gets the height of the selected row.

I need to expand one cell only,  NOT an entire row.[image] Please suggest any approach that might come in handy. (I have simplified the XAML for easy reading, they might not look like the attached images)